# Docker volume mapping generates error : This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace

Tags: angular, docker, docker-volume

Docker version 20.10.21

docker run command without volume mapping works as expected. But when I try to share the source code using volume mapping it ends with **This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace** error.

command works as expected:

```
docker run -p 4200:4200  angular-app
```

command that was not work

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 -v ${pwd}:/web-app/ -v /web-app/node_modules/ angular-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is. There is no error with the command `docker run -p 4200:4200 -v ${pwd}:/web-app/ -v /web-app/node_modules/ angular-app`.

The problem was that I run this command **outside** of the project folder. So that means the project doesn't mounted correctly to the container.

But after I run the command **inside** the project folder the angular app is run without error.

**${pwd}** meaning:

The importance part of the command is **${pwd}**. **${pwd}** is an environment variable that puts path of the current working directory into that command. So if the current working directory is not the project folder it puts path of  other directory than the project.